# Indexing inner lists in "list of lists"

Tags: python-3.x

bigList = [list1,list2,list3]

I need a way to get the name of list1 using the zero index
bigList[0]     just gives you all the items in the list

My original code prints all the items in the lists while the modified one says the index is out of range. I want it to give me the ilness names not all the symptoms.

Original code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDlA9.png

Modified
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qdh2.png

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself and make sure it's a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Never attach pictures of code.

Comment: I only need help in the function